# How to mark a positions in an imageview where the has user clicked

Tags: android, kotlin, imageview

I have an imageview in my android app:

```
  <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="250dp"
                        android:layout_height="250dp"
                        android:id="@+id/imageviewMap"
                />
```

And an onTouchlistener to get the position where the user clicked

```
imageviewMap.setOnTouchListener(object : View.OnTouchListener {
        override fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
            event?.let { e ->
               drawCross(e.x,e.y)
            }
            return true
        }
    })
```

What is want is, that a cross will be drawn in the image (or over it) at the position where the user has clicked. (Multiple times)

How can i realize the drawCross method?

Comment: What you exataly do,you want to draw on custom drawing on imageview?

Comment: I want to add and remove crosses to/from an imageview when the user clicks on it. I don´t need to save the image or something else. ich just want to show the crosses to the user and save the coordinates.

Comment: If you want to draw something then you should cehck this link:https://android--code.blogspot.com/2015/11/android-how-to-draw-line-on-canvas.html

Comment: But just you can make is very simpley:by using two ImageView .One with cross mark and other one is without cross mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my solution. Thanks Kabir for the helpful hint.

I´ve used two image view, one for the background and a tranparent one for the marks

```
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="250dp"
                        android:layout_height="250dp"
                        android:id="@+id/imageviewMap"
                        android:src="@drawable/map"
                />
                <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="250dp"
                        android:layout_height="250dp"
                        android:id="@+id/imageviewCrosses"
                />
```

The touchlistener

```
       imageviewMap.setOnTouchListener { view, event ->
        event?.let { e ->

            if(event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                val x = convertPixelsToDp(e.x, this.applicationContext)
                val y = convertPixelsToDp(e.y, this.applicationContext)
                drawCross(x,y)
            }
        }
        true
    }
```

The pixel dp convert methods

```
fun convertPixelsToDp(px: Float, context: Context): Float{
    return px /  (context.resources.displayMetrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT.toFloat())
}

fun convertDpToPixels(dp: Float, context: Context): Float {
    return dp * (context.resources.displayMetrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT.toFloat())
}
```

The drawCross method (at the moment it draws a circle for test reasons)

```
fun drawCross(x: Float, y: Float) {
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
        250, 
        250,
        Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8
    )

    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
    canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)


    val paint = Paint()
    paint.color = Color.RED
    paint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
    paint.strokeWidth = 1.0f
    paint.isAntiAlias = true

    canvas.drawCircle(
        x, 
        y, 
        10.0f,
        paint 
    )

    imageviewCrosses.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
}
```